# Material UI table error "TypeError: rows.slice is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I have problems about Material UI table.
I searched Material UI table document which is https://material-ui.com/components/tables/.
I wanna know how to apply pagenation with my Jscode "CheckListComponent.js" like "Custom pagination actions" in that documents.
I just changed createData which is in that document to my Jsondata.
Now I'm confusing this Error

```
CustomPaginationActionsTable
C:/workspace/spring-backend-3/frontend/src/component/PagenationTableComponent.js:117
  114 | return (
  115 |     <TableContainer component={Paper}>
  116 |         <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="custom pagination table">
> 117 |             <TableBody>
      | ^  118 |                 {(rowsPerPage > 0
  119 |                     ? rows.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
  120 |                     : rows
View compiled
```

I understand that means but I don't understand where I should fix.
Please tell me how to fix. In Japan, No one tell me how to fix now.

CheckList.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

const CHECKLIST_REST_API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/users';

class CheckListService {

    getList() {
        return axios.get(CHECKLIST_REST_API_URL);
    }
}


export default new CheckListService();
```

PagenationTableComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableFooter from '@material-ui/core/TableFooter';
import TablePagination from '@material-ui/core/TablePagination';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import FirstPageIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FirstPage';
import KeyboardArrowLeft from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowLeft';
import KeyboardArrowRight from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowRight';
import LastPageIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LastPage';
import CheckListService from '../services/CheckList';

const useStyles1 = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        flexShrink: 0,
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(2.5),
    },
}));

function TablePaginationActions(props) {
    const classes = useStyles1();
    const theme = useTheme();
    const { count, page, rowsPerPage, onChangePage } = props;

    const handleFirstPageButtonClick = (event) => {
        onChangePage(event, 0);
    };

    const handleBackButtonClick = (event) => {
        onChangePage(event, page - 1);
    };

    const handleNextButtonClick = (event) => {
        onChangePage(event, page + 1);
    };

    const handleLastPageButtonClick = (event) => {
        onChangePage(event, Math.max(0, Math.ceil(count / rowsPerPage) - 1));
    };

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <IconButton
                onClick={handleFirstPageButtonClick}
                disabled={page === 0}
                aria-label="first page"
            >
                {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <LastPageIcon /> : <FirstPageIcon />}
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton onClick={handleBackButtonClick} disabled={page === 0} aria-label="previous page">
                {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <KeyboardArrowRight /> : <KeyboardArrowLeft />}
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton
                onClick={handleNextButtonClick}
                disabled={page >= Math.ceil(count / rowsPerPage) - 1}
                aria-label="next page"
            >
                {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <KeyboardArrowLeft /> : <KeyboardArrowRight />}
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton
                onClick={handleLastPageButtonClick}
                disabled={page >= Math.ceil(count / rowsPerPage) - 1}
                aria-label="last page"
            >
                {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <FirstPageIcon /> : <LastPageIcon />}
            </IconButton>
        </div>
    );
}

TablePaginationActions.propTypes = {
    count: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    onChangePage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    page: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    rowsPerPage: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

let rows = [];
rows = CheckListService.getList().then((response) => {
    return response.data

});



const useStyles2 = makeStyles({
    table: {
        minWidth: 500,
    },
});

export default function CustomPaginationActionsTable() {
    const classes = useStyles2();
    const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
    const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(5);

    const emptyRows = rowsPerPage - Math.min(rowsPerPage, rows.length - page * rowsPerPage);

    const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
        setPage(newPage);
    };

    const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
        setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
        setPage(0);
    };

    return (
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="custom pagination table">
                <TableBody>
                    {(rowsPerPage > 0
                        ? rows.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                        : rows
                    ).map((row) => (
                        <TableRow key={row.listNo}>
                            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                {row.listNo}
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell style={{ width: 160 }} align="right">
                                {row.saiyouDate}
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell style={{ width: 160 }} align="right">
                                {row.softwareName}
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}

                    {emptyRows > 0 && (
                        <TableRow style={{ height: 53 * emptyRows }}>
                            <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                        </TableRow>
                    )}
                </TableBody>
                <TableFooter>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TablePagination
                            rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25, { label: 'All', value: -1 }]}
                            colSpan={3}
                            count={rows.length}
                            rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                            page={page}
                            SelectProps={{
                                inputProps: { 'aria-label': 'rows per page' },
                                native: true,
                            }}
                            onChangePage={handleChangePage}
                            onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
                            ActionsComponent={TablePaginationActions}
                        />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableFooter>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    );
}
```

PostScript: I wrote a code as mentioned as described below.
then I got new error 'useEffect' is not defined in console.
So I import "import { useState } from 'react';" but dosen't fix.
What should I do to compile?

```
export default function CustomPaginationActionsTable() {
    const classes = useStyles2();
    const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
    const [rows, setRows] = React.useState([]);
    const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(5);

    const emptyRows = rowsPerPage - Math.min(rowsPerPage, rows.length - page * rowsPerPage);

    const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
        setPage(newPage);
    };

    const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
        setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
        setPage(0);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        CheckListService.getList().then((response) => setRows(response.data)); // you may need to check if response.data returns an array, otherwise you will face errors.
    }, [])


    return (
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="custom pagination table">
                <TableBody>
                    {(rowsPerPage > 0
                        ? rows.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                        : rows
                    ).map((row) => (
                        <TableRow key={row.listNo}>
                            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                {row.listNo}
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell style={{ width: 160 }} align="right">
                                {row.saiyouDate}
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell style={{ width: 160 }} align="right">
                                {row.softwareName}
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}

                    {emptyRows > 0 && (
                        <TableRow style={{ height: 53 * emptyRows }}>
                            <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                        </TableRow>
                    )}
                </TableBody>
                <TableFooter>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TablePagination
                            rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25, { label: 'All', value: -1 }]}
                            colSpan={3}
                            count={rows.length}
                            rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                            page={page}
                            SelectProps={{
                                inputProps: { 'aria-label': 'rows per page' },
                                native: true,
                            }}
                            onChangePage={handleChangePage}
                            onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
                            ActionsComponent={TablePaginationActions}
                        />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableFooter>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome sy-torii. you need remove the `row` variable outside from your function. instead, include at your `CustomPaginationActionsTable` a row state. then use `useEffect` to fetch your rows on component mount.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'; // import useEffect
export default function CustomPaginationActionsTable() {
    const classes = useStyles2();
    const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
    const [rows, setRows] = React.useState([]);
    const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(5);

    useEffect(() => {
      CheckListService.getList().then((response) => setRows(response.data)); // you may need to check if response.data returns an array, otherwise you will face errors.
    }, []) // passing an empty array will call this function only at component mount
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching me.
I edit and add new problem in postscript in bottom of my question.
Please tell me.

Comment: you need to import useEffect `import { useEffect } from 'react' `